# FileHelpers - extra column in file not raising an error when FieldQuoted attribute used

Tags: c#, filehelpers

Using FileHelpers.dll version 3.0.1.0, with .net 4.0.

Code to reproduce issue:

create a file Accounts.txt like this:

```
"AccountName","ExtraColumn"
"MR GREEN ","abc"
"MR SMITH ","def"
```

c# Account class :

```
[IgnoreFirst(1)]
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreEmptyLines()]
public class Account
{
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.NotAllow)]
    public string AccountName;

}
```

To read the file:

```
        string fname = @"C:\test\Accounts.txt";

        FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(Account));

        Account[] importNodes =  (Account[])engine.ReadFile(fname);  // XX
```

Now, I would have expected an exception to be raised at line XX, because there are more columns in the file (2), than columns in the "Account" class (1). However, there is no exception raised, and the extra column seems to get silently ignored.

If you change the Account class to remove the "FieldQuoted" attribute, then an exception is indeed raised, like:

> [FileHelpers.BadUsageException]   {"Line: 2 Column: 0. Delimiter ','
>   found after the last field 'AccountName' (the file is wrong or you
>   need to add a field to the record
>   class)"}  FileHelpers.BadUsageException

Can anyone provide some insight ? Should the code with the FieldQuoted attribute indeed raise an exception ? Am I doing something wrong ?

**EDIT** : are there any workarounds, so that an error will be raised when there are more columns in the input file than expected ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[IgnoreFirst(1)]` ignores first line of a file, not the first column.

See description here: [IgnoreFirstAttribute](http://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/T_FileHelpers_IgnoreFirstAttribute.htm)

Removing `FieldQuoted` causes error because you have quoted fields that can't be handled correctly without this attribute.

`FileHelpers` library just ignores the fields from file that don't have corresponding fields in your class.

To ignore first field in each row, you can just add a dummy field to your class definition like this:

```
[IgnoreFirst(1)]
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreEmptyLines()]
public class Account
{
   [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.NotAllow)]
   public string AccountName;

   [FieldValueDiscarded]
   [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.NotAllow)]
   public string Dummy;

}
```

As a workaround I can suggest to add an ordinary `string` dummy field at the end. You can then check if this field is filled in `FileHelperEngine.AfterReadRecord` and throw an exception like this:

```
FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(Account));
engine.AfterReadRecord += engine_AfterReadRecord;
try
{
    Account[] importNodes = (Account[])engine.ReadFile(fname);  // XX
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}


static void engine_AfterReadRecord(EngineBase engine, FileHelpers.Events.AfterReadEventArgs<object> e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(((Account) e.Record).Dummy))
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Unexpected field");
    }
}
```

Comment: i actually DO want to ignore the first line. I removed the FieldQuoted attribute to show that this "bug/feature" appears to have something to do with the FieldQuoted attribute. i.e. when FieldQuoted is removed, the code raises an exception about the extra column.

Comment: thanks for the workaround - that may be the best that can be done. Anyone know if this issue still exists with the latest version of FileHelpers ?

Comment: I've checked GitHub sources here: https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/blob/master/ . This seems to be a behavior inconsistency in FileHelpers/Fields/DelimitedField.cs. It only throws this exception if last field doesn't have `FieldQuoted` attribute and file contains more fields than class.

Comment: Hi, I will be adding a test case to check this behavior and verify if is a bug, and fix it, thanks !!

Comment: Here is the test case, with an Account class with two fields it works fine https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/commit/90c4e731d1a4fa2bfc2b55f72a93df244de2f59b